# how to enable reflection in libgdx to use json parsing for my game

Tags: json, gwt, libgdx

I have been working on project for a while now and just started testing the GWT backend. When I tried it gave the error "Error reading file: poly-ui.json"

I read on the libgdx wiki that i must enable reflection on the GWT backend for the JSON resource to work but the example given has me confused and i am not sure how to enable reflection (if that is even the issue)

Thanks in advance.

Wiki page i was talking about : https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationConfiguration#HTML5/GWT

Answer (score 3):

To use reflection with GWT, you need to tell the compiler the classes for which you need reflection information to be generated. You do this by including configuration properties in your GWT module definition (*.gwt.xml).

Further, you must use the LibGDX Reflection API for any reflection you do. The Json utilities in LibGDX do this already, so if you just want to use Json, you shouldn't have to be concerned with using the Reflection API.

See the LibGDX wiki[1] at GitHub for details on how to add reflected classes to your GWT module, and also how to use the Reflection API.

[1] https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reflection